# Accessing Nested URL Using Blade in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I am trying to access a page using a nested url in Laravel 5.1 but I have reached a dead end.
I would like to make a **GET** request with a parameter in the middle of the url. To be precise, **cars/{cars}/edit**.
This is my code:

In the routes file

```
Route::resource('cars', 'carController');
```

In the cars controller file

```
class carController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){

       $cars = Car::all();
       return view('carshome', compact('cars'));
    }

    public function edit($id){  
        return 'Welcome:  '.$id.'page';
    }
}
```

In the carshome blade template file

```
@foreach ($cars as $car)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $car->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $car->type }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a href = {{url('/cars',[$car->name])}}>
           <i class="fi-clipboard-pencil"></i>
        </a>
        <a href = {{url('/cars',[$car->name])}}>
           <i class="fi-x-circle"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

In the car model file

```
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'type'
    ];
}
```

The helper function [url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-url) can take parameters as part of the url. Am not sure how I can it to create the custom url. How can I access the url resource using blade?

Comment: tbh, using `Route::resource('cars', 'carController');` would save you from using `url(..)`. you could use `route('cars.edit', [$car->name])` simple as that. ps. confirm it with [documentation on restful resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Comment: As @Tezla wrote, but you can still use `url()`, like `url('cars', [$car->id, 'edit'])`.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Tezla, it works. I don't know where to click to mark your comment as correct.

Comment: Thank you, @lamzozo. Your answer is equally right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to mark the question as answered. As [@Tezla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4648586/tezla) shared:
In the carshome blade template file I can use:

```
route('cars.edit', [$car->name])
```

[@lamzozo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428337/iamzozo) suggested another working method to use in the carshome blade template file:

```
url('cars', [$car->name, 'edit'])
```